# Raycaster in scratch.mit.edu isn't working

Tags: list, 3d, maze, raycasting, mit-scratch

I need help with a raycasting script I'm working on. For some reason, instead of drawing the map, it just draws a solid line on one side. I am following the Scratch Wiki's tutorials as well as using a working version. Here's my code. https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/348658266/ Due to the complexity of this project, it is hard to create a MRE, but keep in mind that I can't seem to move around and the iteration code is going into numbers outside the range it should.

Comment: The code you posted seems to work...

Comment: I fixed it through the Scratch Forums

Comment: Then you should either answer your own question with what helped so that other people may be helped by it, or delete it.